# How to prevent column resize below the ctual size

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am working on extJS grid column and I can resize my grid column. But I want my column won't be resize below the actual width. It mean I can not resize the width to left side.

How can I get this.

What I am trying here is ,

```
columnresize : function(ct,column,width,eOpts){
            var actualColumn = this.myXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('column');
            var actualSize = actualColumn.width;
            if(actualSize > width){
                column.resizable = false;
            }
        }
```

But in this case column is resizing and then no option for resizable.

I just want it won't resize below the actual length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`minWidth`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-minWidth):

> The minimum value in pixels which this Component will set its width
>   to.

Comment: I am already getting a width from the configuration. On top of that I need to set `minWidth` is it ?